# Uncaught exception 'PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013]

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to get my mysql db up and running on amazon rds however I am running into an issue. When trying to connect to my db via php from a remote server to pull information I am getting the following error.

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013]
>   Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication
>   packet', system error: 110'

And it points to the line that shows my dbhostname username password etc. What can I do to get past this error. The hostname etc seems to be fine as I can connect to the db using mysql workbench using the same credentials. What am I missing?

Note PDO and Mysql is installed on the remote php server

Comment: What are you using for dbhostname?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the hostname is the endpoint. I solved it though it is a firewall error. I was blocking the connection via the firewall

Comment: Ok, well post that as an answer along with whatever nudged you into looking at the firewall. It could be very useful to others that are having this same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this was an issue with the inbound of Firewall rules on my AWS RDS server. What made me think it was a firewall error is that the error referred to packets and losing connections. Also that the same code was working before and the PDO extensions not installed on PHP gave an entirely different error.